# Using EventBus to finish an Activity from Base Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

Working on an existing project, I found this rather uncommon piece of implementation (to me at least). Since I am not in contact with the previous developer who already left, and before I dismiss this as a case of simply copy and pasting code from another part of our codebase, I would like to ask the SO community about this.

Here's your everyday activity that extends BaseActivity, and the implementation:

```
class SomeActivity : BaseActivity(R.layout.some_activity) {
    ...
    private fun close() {
        if(backToMain)
            finish()
        } 
        else
            goToMain(this)
    }

    companion object {
        fun goToMain(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
            EventBus.getDefault().post(Event(Event.Type.ActivityFinish))
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In BaseActivity.kt, there's a subscription to the event which calls finish().

```
@Subscribe override fun onEvent(event: Event) {
    when (event.type) {
        Event.Type.ActivityFinish -> super.finish()
        else -> {}
    }
}
```

Now, **why would anyone use EventBus to call** `Activity.finish()` from the extended BaseActivity, instead of just calling it then and there (in the above SignActivity)? **Even if SomeActivity were actually a fragment**, you could simply call `getActivity.finish()`.

*With regards to the intent flags, you could also use [`Activity.finishAffinity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) to finish all activities in the back stack if your min SDK is 16.

Thanks in advance for feeding my curiosity. :D

Comment: it could be a scenario , `sign IN => signUp(on successful signup , kill signIN and take user to Someother screen) => Somesceen`

Comment: That would actually be a legit situation. However, that implies a communication between two activities, not an activity and it's extended base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's the deal with this. After some staring on the screen a couple of times and working more with the codebase, I found that the previous developer actually used the `goToMain` function from other activities (do people really do this? O_o). Nonetheless, since the "Activity" object is still passed, there is no reason that I could think of for using an EventBus in this particular scenario (because you can just call `activity.finish()`).

**In conclusion**, the developer probably just adapted this chunk of code from a different part of the app, thinking this is how it works.

---

What is **[EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)**?

> EventBus is an Android optimized event bus that simplifies
>   communication **between** Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc.

i.e. Not running a static method to call an activity's own extended functions.

Comment: So, writing comment is really important :)

Comment: @BakaWaii Indeed it is

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - This answer was before mentioning that project is using minimum Api level 16.

I looked into your code and I think developer had very good intention behind that. He wants to clear all Activities from stack. Like here he used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but it requires API level > 11.

By adding subscription in `BaseActivity` we can make sure that `Activity` will no longer exist after broadcasting `Event.Type.ActivityFinish` tag with a use of `EventBus`. That method will work as a safer approach if you think about logout case where you are going to clear your stack.

Comment: With regards to the intent flags, you could simply call `Activity.finishAffinity()` and this would, in simple words, call `finish()` for all activities in the back stack. So, I don't think this explains why you would use an EventBus.

Comment: Again `Activity.finishAffinity` came after API level 16. For more check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497151/activity-finishaffinity-vs-intent-flag-activity-new-task-intent-flag-activit and I don't think there is anything bad to use this approach to kill activities.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance of API level. Yes, you are right. The flags are an OK thing to use (just that my project specifically is minSdk 16). Nonetheless, I don't think it's the reason why EventBus is used because you could simply call `finish()` at the end there.

Comment: If your project is using minimum 16, which you mentioned now then these subscriptions have no meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Rahul :D